# Emacs dirtree, How to delete files and refresh

Tags: emacs-dirtree

I am using [dirtree](https://github.com/zkim/emacs-dirtree) in emacs. The problem is that when I add new files it never refreshes its structure. Also, coming from a Visual studio background it would be nice to be able to delete files directly out of the tree, is this possible? (I mean I know with emacs all things are possible, but was wondering if someone has solved this problem already).

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh the tree by pressing `g`. This refreshes the tree you're currently in (not the whole tree, though!).

Unfortunately, you can't delete a single file or directory except for the root node (which is really stupid). To delete the root node, type `D` and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to refresh just kill buffer of dirtree, and open dirtree again.
C-x k ---- kill buffer
M-x dirtree RET